# Excel Solver ignores Binary Constraint

Tags: excel, constraints, linear-programming, excel-solver

I have a minimization of a price problem.
Table is as follows:

|  | Column B | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Price | 380 | 450 |
| Quantity |  |  |
| Portions | 4 | 5 |
| Binary | 1 or 0 | 1 or 0 |

I should set a menu of minimum of 6 different positions to minimize price.
I have such contraints:

1. A certain position should be included
2. The number of positions should be >= 6
3. The number of pieces should be >=50 (each position on the menu is a certain amount of pieces varying from 1 to 14)

So in order to keep track of the number of different positions (variety), i have binary variables which is 1 if the quantity of the position is > 0, and 0 otherwise.

However, the solver just ignores the binary constraints of
[this position's binary variable] > 0 (1 constraint)
[Number of positions] >= 6 (sum of all the binary variables)

Why?? It says the optimal solution is found and all the constraints were considered. Why does it give me the Number of positions = 1 (choosing the most cheap position with the most of pieces).

I know it's the most affordable choice, but I need variety!

I've tried to put the constraint on the price and maximize the Pieces, the variety reaches 6. So why can't it set this price when I'm minimizing????

I don't understand. In the minimization problem there's no constraint on the price, why it avoids constraints?

None of the advices from the forum like "make higher presicion" or "turn off the ignore integer constraints" worked.

Comment: What is a position? Why is your column B heading repeated? How do we reproduce this problem?